# Suppose that a ≠ 0R is not a zerodivisor in a ring R. Show that ab = ac, with b and c in R, implies that b = c.

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose that a ≠ 0R is not a zerodivisor in a ring R.

Show that ab = ac, with b and c in R, implies that b = c.

I kind know the idea but don't know how to write a approiate proof... help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $ab=ac$ is equivalent to $a(b-c)=0$. Since $a$ is not a zero divisor, $a(b-c)=0$ implies...